# laravels Auth::logout logs out users that are logged in another browsers

Tags: laravel

my problem is with laravel auth::logout functionality,
Imagine a user is jept logged in, in different browsers and when I call Auth::logout in one of the browser, it logges out from the other browsers out too,
Is there anyway tosolve this problem in laravel itself?

Edit: this is real problem, when a user is kept logged in in his pc and logs out from another computer, which causes to be logged out from his own pc too.

Comment: I don't see any reason to do that. I'm really surprised that Laravel doesn't logouts user if he logs in another browser. Each normal user uses one browser when using page so you should not care if he is being logged out in another browser.

Comment: No i Mean if you are kept logged in in your pc and you visit your account in another computer, if you log out in the another computer, then you are no longer kept logged in in your pc ;)

Comment: Ok, and what is wrong with this solution? If you as a user wants to be logged out, you are being logged out and for me it's a good solution. What if you changed password on the other PC? You would expect still not being logged at your PC even if password has been changed?

Comment: So think about this, you are logged in you yahoo account in your house and keep logged in, and you login to your account in your office but you want to sign out at your office from your account and still be kept logged in, what do you do?

Comment: And what's the problem to log in again at home? Such things could cause potential security problems as you @TheShiftExchange mentioned. For me if you log out you should be logged out no matter on which PC and for anyone who knows their password or saves password in browser/software at home it won't be to hard to log in again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality was a specific feature [added to Laravel 4.1.26 as a security measure](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1.26).

The reason is the exact scenario you provide - if you leave yourself logged in on Computer A, and log yourself out of Computer B - this ensures you are fully logged out of all computers.

It is a security measure. Before this update, if a remember cookie was hijacked by another malicious user, the cookie would remain valid for a long period of time, even after the true owner of the account reset their password, logged out, etc

Comment: thanks for your answer, but one question, how does websites like facebook do these staff? ;)